# How to debug an issue with Zendesk App as console.log is not working

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

```
topBarClient.request(settings).then(
  function (data) {
    console.log("data",data);
    showTaskData(data);
    if (data.status === 200) {
      onSuccess(JSON.parse(data.responseText));
    } else {
      onFailure(data.status);
    }
  },
  function (response) {
    console.log("error", response);
    onFailure(response.status);
  }
);
```

onFailure is working but not able to get the error out
Is there a way to test this locally?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` works fine, if it's not working then it is not getting called probably due to some exception in the line above `console.log`.

If you face any problem you can render html component like div to dislplay the text for debugging purpose.